# Apache Camel is waiting for namespace handlers

Tags: namespaces, apache-camel, blueprint

I am trying to implement Apache Camel router for message signatures as described on the Apache Cookbook there:
https://github.com/CamelCookbook/camel-cookbook-examples/blob/master/camel-cookbook-security/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/signatures-context.xml

I am using Karaf 5.7.0 (Part of Talend ESB) and Camel 2.12.1
The camel-crypto bundle have dependency on "spring-crypto-utils" (http://springcryptoutils.com/) thas has been added to Blueprint configuration according to the Camel Cookbook example.

There is my blueprint config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
 xmlns:crypt="http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt"
 default-activation="eager"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
        http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt.xsd
        ">

 <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="mock.jms"
  update-strategy="reload" placeholder-prefix="jms:${">
  <cm:default-properties>
   <cm:property name="broker" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
   <cm:property name="destinationstd" value="stdlog" />
   <cm:property name="destinationsat" value="satlog" />
  </cm:default-properties>
 </cm:property-placeholder>


 <!-- Camel route -->
 <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="jms:${broker}" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="processor" class="mock.jms.Processor" />
 
 <crypt:keystore id="keyStore"
                  location="classpath:keystore.jks"
                  password="keystorePassword"/>
   <crypt:keystore id="trustStore"
                  location="classpath:truststore.jks"
                  password="truststorePassword"/>

 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route>
   <from uri="activemq:topic:stdlog" />
   <log message="MessageId: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}"/>
   <!-- <to uri="log:cz.icz.kbe?level=ERROR"/>  -->
   <to uri="log:cz.icz.kbe?showHeaders=true test"/>
   <choice>
    <when>
     <simple>${body} regex '(?is).*EventMarker.*:.*Audit.*'</simple>
     <bean ref="processor" />
     <to uri="activemq:topic:satlog" />
    </when>
   </choice>
  </route>
 </camelContext>
 <!-- End Camel route -->

</blueprint>
```

I am trying to implement very simple Camel route that filters messages from ActiveMQ that fits to the provided regex and add SHA1WithRSA signature to the message header (camel-crypto functionality) but when I simply added  tags to load keystore content (this keystores will be later used for signatures) the bundle cannot start and hangs in GracePeriod with log message:

```html
2015-06-02 18:25:35,172 | INFO  | Refresh Packages | e.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl  307 | 11 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.2.0 | Bundle jms is waiting for namespace handlers [http://springcryptoutils.com/schema/crypt]
```

It seems that camel cannot find namespace handler for "springcryptoutils" namespace. The code compiles correctly and correctly generates bundle, the problem occurs during deployment in karaf (manual deployment using /deploy folder). The karaf does not complain with dependencies of my bundle, the karaf command "headers" does not show anything suspiscious:

```html
karaf@trun> headers 292

JMS Mock (292)
--------------
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Bnd-LastModified = 1433262312090
Build-Jdk = 1.8.0_40
Built-By = belunek
Tool = Bnd-2.4.0.201411031534

Bundle-Blueprint = OSGI-INF/blueprint/jms.cli.xml
Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-SymbolicName = jms
Bundle-Version = 1.0.0
Bundle-Name = JMS Mock

Export-Package =
        mock.jms;version=1.0.0,
        mock.jms.cli;version=1.0.0
Import-Package =
        org.apache.felix.gogo.commands;version="[0.10,1)",
        org.apache.karaf.shell.console;version="[2.3,3)",
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;version="[2.2,3)",
        javax.jms,
        org.apache.activemq,
        org.apache.activemq.camel.component,
        org.apache.camel;version="[2.12,3)",
        org.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",
        org.slf4j,
        org.apache.felix.service.command;status=provisional;version="[0.10,1)"
```

Please any ideas where the problem is?

Edited:
I installed all necessary bundles by simple puttng jars into karaf deploy directory. The goal was to install camel-crypto and all dependecies required by this bundle.
Theres is list of aditional deployed JARs:
activemq-camel-5.7.0.jar
bcpg-jdk15on-1.52.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar
camel-crypto-2.12.1.jar
spring-crypto-utils-1.4.0.jar

There is complete POM listing - contains some non necessary parts due to my tries and fails

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>mock.jms</groupId>
<artifactId>jms</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>JMS Mock</name>

<properties>
    <osgi.version>4.3.1</osgi.version>
    <bundle-plugin.version>2.4.0</bundle-plugin.version>
    <karaf.version>2.3.1</karaf.version>
    <activemq.version>5.7.0</activemq.version>
    <camel.version>2.12.1</camel.version>
    <jackson.version>2.2.2</jackson.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>${osgi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>${osgi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.console</artifactId>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.commands</artifactId>
        <version>${karaf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-xmlsecurity</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-security</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--suppress NonOsgiMavenDependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.spring-crypto-utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-crypto-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>${bundle-plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <_nouses>true</_nouses>
                    <_noee>true</_noee>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.apache.felix.service.command,
                        org.apache.felix.gogo.commands,
                        org.apache.karaf.shell.console,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        mock.jms*;version=${project.version}
                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if the feature has been installed , i.e features: install camel-crypto. Them try to wrap install the spring-Crupto-utils using the command install -s wrap:mvn:com.google.code.spring-crypto-utils/spring-crypto-utils/$version. This should resolve the namespace handler issue

Comment: I have install camel-crypto and spring-crypto-utils by simple download JAR from Maven central and put them into karaf /deploy directory. The bundles  has ben succesfully installed. 
The came-crupto bundle also requires instal of some dependent bundles (e.g Bouncycastle crypto libs).
There is complete set of JAR that I put to the deploy  directory until camel-crypto stops complaining for missing dependencies:
activemq-camel-5.7.0.jar
bcpg-jdk15on-1.52.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar
camel-crypto-2.12.1.jar
spring-crypto-utils-1.4.0.jar

Comment: This is due to missing dependencies. Install the camel feature into karaf. This is much easier than deploying by copying to deployment directory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I cannot use remote maven server because the container in on server without internet access. There is no problem with dependencies, camel-crypto bundle does not complain with dependencies. Problem is that camel does not find XML namespace handler provided by spring-crypto-utils which is correctly installed and camel-crypto recognizes it.

Comment: Is there anything in your `maven-bundle-plugin` configuration which may exclude some part of the spring-crypto-utils bundle?

Comment: There is no excludes in maven-bundle-plugin. I have added complete POM listing.